# Android picasso image's edge is cut after transform

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I am using Picasso to transform an image into a rounded square image.
It also has the border. But when I put this image to Imageview, it's edge is cut. Any solution for this? Android version is 4.4.2.

My Imageview looks like this.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/edge_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edge_margin"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Below is code.

```
@Override public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    int ratio = source.getWidth() / mDisplayWidth;
    float strokeWidth = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, Constants.SHAPE_STROKE_WIDTH, mDisplayMetrics) * ratio;
    float radius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, Constants.SQUARE_RADIUS, mDisplayMetrics) * ratio;

    int x = (int) (mRectF.left * ratio);
    int y = (int) (mRectF.top * ratio);
    int width = (int) ((mRectF.right - mRectF.left) * ratio);
    int height = (int) ((mRectF.bottom - mRectF.top) * ratio);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, width, height);

    source.recycle();

    return getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, radius, strokeWidth);
}

@Override public String key() {
    return "card_square";
}

private Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int color, float cornerSizePx, float borderSizePx) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    // prepare canvas for transfer
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerSizePx, cornerSizePx, paint);

    // draw bitmap
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    bitmap.recycle();

    // draw border
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(borderSizePx);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerSizePx, cornerSizePx, paint);

    return output;
}`
```

Comment: Have you tried `scaleType` `fitCenter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used in one of my previous project to transform an image into a rounded image:

```
public Bitmap getRoundedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }
```